# Find -perm finds file (or something else) that dosent exist

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hello i am new in the world of linux and i have a simple question:
I created a directory named testfiles and 10 textfiles inside of it with various permissions.
I tried using find -perm -u=wr | wc -l in order to count all files with rw prem for user but it counts 1 more file than it is supposed to have. I then used find -perm -u=wr to see the list and realized there is an extra line in the beginning which i am not sure what it is can someone help? How do I get rid of that?

[image]

Comment: Do not make screenshots of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '.' and '..' are references to the current directory and the parent directory respectively. These exist in all linux directories. As these are treated as directories, you can ignore them by using the '-type' option of the find command, where 'f' specifies files only.

```
find -perm -u=wr -type f | wc -l
```

Note that the find command as you have it will recursively find files if another directory exists where you are running the command. You can limit it to the current directory only by using the max depth option. Run 'man find' in the terminal to see all the other options you have with the find command.